# Why not Fourier Transform spectroscopy in the VIS?

Tags: visible-light, fourier-transform, interference, spectroscopy

There is large amount of scientific and industrial research regarding Fourier Transform spectroscopy (FTS) in the infrared region. However the isn't much about FTS in the visible light spectrum?

Is there an intrinsic physical or technical limitation?

Thanks.

Comment: Plenty of folks do visible and UV Fourier transform spectroscopy as a Google search (or Web of Science) will readily reveal.

Comment: See https://opg.optica.org/ao/fulltext.cfm?uri=ao-17-9-1327&id=21932 for example (from 1978): "The extension of the Fourier transform spectroscopy (FTS) to short wavelength (the visible and uv range) has already been proposed several times in the past.[1],[2] However, the first high resolution work done with a Fourier spectrometer equipped with photomultipliers appeared only in 1971.[3] The technical difficulties encountered do not explain the long delay with which these spectra were obtained, so it is of interest to recall the fundamental factors responsible for the FTS success..."